# QTP Script to Get Field Values from QC

Tags: hp-quality-center

I want to get the count of status(Pass/Fail) of all testcases present in QC by checking the execution grid.
What is the method to retrieve the status and execution date of a test case ?
Currently I am only able to get the test case name.

Code:

```
Set treeMgr = gTDConn.TestSetTreeManager 
Set tstTree = treeMgr.NodeByPath(TestSetPath) 
Set tstFactory = tstTree.testSetFactory 
Set tsetList = tstFactory.NewList("") 

For Each tset In tsetList 
  msgbox tset.Name 
next
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @Robert  Set treeMgr = gTDConn.TestSetTreeManager  Set tstTree = treeMgr.NodeByPath(TestSetPath)  Set tstFactory = tstTree.testSetFactory  Set tsetList = tstFactory.NewList("")  For Each tset In tsetList  msgbox tset.Name  next

Comment: Thanks. I've added it to your question. You're more likely to get a decent response that way.